# lossless cutting of AAC sound file

Tags: mp3, aac

I have a longer duration AAC sound file that I want to split. It is an OST (Original Sound Tracks) compilation containing mostly voiceless / without singing soundtrack music, but also some songs with singing voice: intro, outro, and one that has an opera that is part of that episode. I want to create a version without any singing OSTs.

I know that there is a program for editing / cutting mp3 files without decoding and encoding - *mp3splt* - but is there a solution for AAC as well?
System: x86-64 Linux.

"file" tells me about the sound file this:

```
MPEG ADTS, AAC, v4 LC, 44.1 kHz, stereo
```

Comment: Try ffmpeg (not sure if it supports *lossless* AAC cutting, but it's worth trying that out)

Comment: ffmpeg indeed supports cutting without reencoding for any audio or video format. Be aware that "clicks" may be introduced between consecutive tracks: that is because in compressed audio, frames may rely on information of the surrounding frames. If you losslessly cut, the previous or following frames are removed, and accordingly, the frames on the edge cannot be reconstructed anymore correctly. For practical purposes, you will not hear artefacts if you cut/join on silence points.

Comment: If you are interested in using FFmpeg there is a `segment` filter. More than happy to provide an example in a formal answer or you can see the gory details here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment By the sound of your question you would after the `segment_times` option...